# What is the correct std::set_union code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set-union

[This site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union) claims that `set_union` is equivalent to the following code:

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator set_union ( InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                             InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
                             OutputIterator result )
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (*first1<*first2) *result++ = *first1++;
    else if (*first2<*first1) *result++ = *first2++;
    else { *result++ = *first1++; first2++; }

    if (first1==last1) return copy(first2,last2,result);
    if (first2==last2) return copy(first1,last1,result);
  }
}
```

But that seems strange: Won't that crash (or result in other undefined behavior) if one of the ranges is empty? Shouldn't the two `if` clauses be at the beginning of the `while` loop, instead of the end?

Comment: cplusplus.com is not an authoritative reference.  ISO/IEC
14882 is, and that does not contain sample code for `set_union`, merely the specification (which allows the input sequences to be empty).

Comment: Actually I've never liked cplusplus.com, it's not precise in the details.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I like it as an index :)

Comment: I suggest a [better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that it looks totally broken. For comparison, here is the STLport code:

```
template <class _InputIter1, class _InputIter2, class _OutputIter,
          class _Compare>
_OutputIter __set_union(_InputIter1 __first1, _InputIter1 __last1,
                        _InputIter2 __first2, _InputIter2 __last2,
                        _OutputIter __result, _Compare __comp) {
  _STLP_DEBUG_CHECK(_STLP_PRIV __check_range(__first1, __last1))
  _STLP_DEBUG_CHECK(_STLP_PRIV __check_range(__first2, __last2))
  while (__first1 != __last1 && __first2 != __last2) {
    if (__comp(*__first1, *__first2)) {
      _STLP_VERBOSE_ASSERT(!__comp(*__first2, *__first1), _StlMsg_INVALID_STRICT_WEAK_PREDICATE)
      *__result = *__first1;
      ++__first1;
    }
    else if (__comp(*__first2, *__first1)) {
      _STLP_VERBOSE_ASSERT(!__comp(*__first1, *__first2), _StlMsg_INVALID_STRICT_WEAK_PREDICATE)
      *__result = *__first2;
      ++__first2;
    }
    else {
      *__result = *__first1;
      ++__first1;
      ++__first2;
    }
    ++__result;
  }
  return _STLP_STD::copy(__first2, __last2, _STLP_STD::copy(__first1, __last1, __result));
}
```